# Unrecognized selector sent to instance [Error] Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Instead of using google sign in button, I designed my own google login button and connected the button to View Controller but I keep receiving "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController signInGoogleButtonDidTouch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance " error.

I need help making my button as a sign in button.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate{


// Customized Google sign-in button
@IBAction func signInGoogleButtonDidTouch(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Sign in as Google user
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
}
```

Comment: Check in IB if your connection is correct.

Comment: The class of your UIViewController in IB is not set to `SignInViewController`.